# Rolling a Matplotlib colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am trying to plot the months in the Southern hemisphere but as winter is in July (7), I would like the colorbar to start from July and end in June, i.e. [7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6]. Is there a straight forward way to do this so that July corresponds to the darkest blue in the colorbar below instead of the colorbar starting from January (1,2,...,12)?

[image: Month in colors]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just extending the months:

```
month = pd.DatetimeIndex(Apl2.time).month.values
month[month<7] += 12
```